# Bookmark launcher for Chrome

Tags: chrome, bookmark

I would like an extension that allows me to search for and launch bookmarks for Chrome.

Key Requirements:

- Ability to search bookmarks with history excluded (unlike the omnibar)
- Keyboard shortcut

Optional

- Uses more of the screen than the omni-bar does
- Display of bookmark titles more prominent than the URL

Comment: You could just open the bookmark manager. Bookmarks > Bookmark Manager. On OSX, the shortcut is CMD + OPT + B. You can find the Windows shortcut next to the 'Bookmark Manager' text under 'Bookmarks'.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Pine Bookmark Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pine-bookmark-explorer/fmbnigjgadncodobgodkecnkahdnggpm):

- beautiful interface
- can set keyboard shortcut (more info below)
- can search bookmarks
- uses whole window
- more bookmark title/tile than URL

To set the keyboard shortcut, go to chrome://extensions/, go to the bottom of the page, and click Keyboard Shortcuts. Find 'Pine Bookmark Explorer', and type in your preferred shortcut.

Make sure you go to Settings (within the extension) and set the 'Homepage' to be 'Bookmarks Bar', so when you press the shortcut, the bookmarks open straight away!

Set the shortcut:

[image]

Extension:

[image]

Set 'Homepage' as 'Bookmarks Bar':

[image]

Comment: Pine is a nice homepage replacement. It's a shame though that you have to use the mouse to open the bookmarks :-(

Comment: @Casebash If you mean actually opening Pine, I said how to put a shortcut to *open* it. If you mean actually opening the bookmarks, you could just use the TAB key and ENTER when you reach the bookmark...

Comment: The tab command requires me to tab through the whole sidebar first :-(

Comment: @Casebash You could try using something like this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-hotkey-shortcut/hfjofdnkkjjpjmkjmidfacfnfkmceoll?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [Bookmark Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-search/hhmokalkpaiacdofbcddkogifepbaijk).

It isn't exactly what you wanted, but does what you want.

As you already know, typing into the omnibar finds bookmarks *and* history, so what this extension does is gives you an option to search only for bookmarks while in the omnibar.

You use it by:

- typing `bm` (short for bookmark) in the omnibar
- pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>
- typing your bookmark (url/name)

Extension:

[image]

Options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered [Dewey](http://deweyapp.io/). Unlike the other apps, it at least provides decent support for launching bookmarks using the keyboard. Sadly, it doesn't yet have support for launching the app with a keyboard shortcut. I haven't figured out how to do this yet.